# Efficient strtod in Java?

Tags: java, string, performance, memory, floating-point

So I have this Java program that I use to munch through several terabytes of data. Performance is a concern.

I've profiled the app, and a large fraction of all memory allocations as well as a large fraction of CPU time come from performing one simple operation:

I have an array of ASCII chars. I know that the characters from offset `i` to offset `j` represent a floating-point number. I need to extract that floating-point number into a `double`.

The naive `Double.parseDouble(new String(buf, i, j - i))` does the job. However, this is where a lot of time is spent and a lot of memory allocations come from, probably because:

- `new String()` creates a new object, creates an internal `char[]` array
  and copies the characters into the array;
- `Double.parseDouble()`
  creates a [`FloatingDecimal`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html) object, and too creates a `char[]` array,
  also copying the characters into it.

All these allocations and all this copying are not really necessary. Can I avoid them?

What I'd really like is a [`strtod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strtod)-like function that would take a `char[]` (or a `byte[]`) as well as start/end offsets, and return a `double`.

Any suggestions? Should I roll out my own? Should I write a JNI wrapper around `strtod`? Should I use some Java library that's already out there?

Comment: Actually, String.substring method doesn't copy the initial array. It might be useful if String constructor is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I have done in the past is write a parser for ByteBuffer (to avoid byte to char encoding conversion) to double and visa-versa. If you can avoid creating any objects it can be much faster.  This approach works for memory mapped files avoiding some copy costs as well.

The core code looks like the following. It doesn't handle exponents, but you can add that.

```
@Override
public double read() throws BufferUnderflowException {
  long value = 0;
  int exp = 0;
  boolean negative = false;
  int decimalPlaces = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  while (true) {
    byte ch = buffer.get();
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
      while (value >= MAX_VALUE_DIVIDE_10) {
        value >>>= 1;
        exp++;
      }
      value = value * 10 + (ch - '0');
      decimalPlaces++;
    } else if (ch == '-') {
      negative = true;
    } else if (ch == '.') {
      decimalPlaces = 0;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return asDouble(value, exp, negative, decimalPlaces);
}
```

[The full code](http://code.google.com/p/core-java-performance-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/code/java/core/parser/ByteBufferTextDoubleReader.java)

It stops as soon as it gets any byte it doesn't expect e.g. a `,` or `\n`

Answer (score 5):

I'd look at the source for `java.lang.Double`, copy out the code that does `parseDouble` to my own helper class and modify it to work on `char[]` with `offset` and `length` directly.

Comment: This is an option, except that this is basically what `FloatingDecimal` does and it's about ~3K lines of code with plenty of memory allocations scattered throughout. Don't really fancy hacking that if I can help it (the JNI route sounds a lot more appealing).

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity I copied the strtod function into Java and got ~10 time speedup comparing to Double.parseDouble(String) method (even without creating new Strings in loop). But maybe that's not enough for your implementation.

Micro benchmarking gives:

Double.parseDouble(): 1.6M conversions/second
Java strtod() method: 10.5M conversions/second

Comment: (+1) Awesome, thanks for doing this. Out of interest, which `strtod` implementation did you take?

Comment: from this link: [http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_8/missing/strtod.c](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_8/missing/strtod.c)

Answer (score 1):

If you know an efficient C implementation, you could write a wrapper for it with JNI.

Comment: You'd be adding JNI overhead though (I assume there is some cost to it).

Comment: If it's a static function, the overhead is probably quite reasonable. The only way to find out is to try it!